# Etsy API Image upload error: The request body is too large

Tags: c#, oauth, etsy

My question is related to this article: [Etsy API Image upload error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221840/etsy-api-image-upload-error/50698091#50698091) but from a C# point of view.

Everything else works, eg I'm able to make an authenticated call to Etsy to create listings but now I've started getting an error "**The request body is too large**" when trying to attach images to an Etsy listing.  The request used to work as I have an example response, but now it simple fails.

What I normally do is to set up a Rest Client with the keys, tokens from Etsy. Then I set up a Rest Request and pass it to the Rest Client's Execute method viz:

```
...
// Set up the rest client...
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

restClient.BaseUrl = new System.Uri("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/");
restClient.Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, PermanentAccessTokenKey, PermanentAccessTokenSecret);


// Set up the request...
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

request.Resource = "An Etsy end point";
request.Method = Method.POST;
...

IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
...
```

I'm using RestSharp to handle the OAuthentication.

The main bit of interest is this:

```
...
                        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                        request.AddParameter("image", localImageFilenames[i]);
                        request.AddParameter("type", "image/" + imageType);
                        request.AddParameter("rank", imageRank++);
                        request.AddFile("image", imageByteArray, localImageFilenames[i], "image/" + imageType);

                        request.Resource = "/listings/{0}/images".Replace("{0}", etsyListingId.ToString()); // eg "/listings/559242925/images";
                        request.Method = Method.POST;
                        response = restClient.Execute(request);

...
```

Where the response is:

```
"StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 29)"
    Content: "The request body is too large"
    ContentEncoding: ""
    ContentLength: 29
    ContentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
    Cookies: Count = 3
    ErrorException: null
    ErrorMessage: null
    Headers: Count = 9
    IsSuccessful: false
    ProtocolVersion: {1.1}
    RawBytes: {byte[29]}
    Request: {RestSharp.RestRequest}
    ResponseStatus: Completed
    ResponseUri: {https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/605119036/images}
    Server: "Apache"
    StatusCode: BadRequest
    StatusDescription: "Bad Request"
    content: "The request body is too large"
```

The main routine then that takes a connected rest client:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Upload and attach the list of images to the specified Etsy listing id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="restClient">Connected Etsy client</param>
    /// <param name="localImageFilenames">List of local images to attach to the listing (ordered in rank order).</param>
    /// <param name="etsyListingId">The Etsy listing's listing id to which images will be attached.</param>
    public void AttachImagesToProduct(RestClient restClient, List<string> imageFilenames, int etsyListingId, string localTemporaryDirectory)
    {
        int imageRank = 1;
        string localImageFilename = null;
        List<string> localImageFilenames = new List<string>();


        // Before we reattach images, Etsy only caters for local image filesname eg ones that reside on the user's PC (and not http://...).
        // So, if the images beign with http... then we need to download them locally, upload them and then delete...
        for (int i = 0; i < imageFilenames.Count; i++)
        {
            if (imageFilenames[i].ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("http"))
            {
                // Download...
                localImageFilename = Orcus.CommonLibrary.Images.DownloadRemoteImageFile(imageFilenames[i], localTemporaryDirectory);
            }
            else
            {
                localImageFilename = imageFilenames[i];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localImageFilename))
            {
                localImageFilenames.Add(localImageFilename);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < localImageFilenames.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(localImageFilenames[i]) && etsyListingId > 0)
                {
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413184/converting-a-jpeg-image-to-a-byte-array-com-exception
                    // https://blog.tyrsius.com/restsharp-file-upload/
                    // https://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/uploading-files-to-remote-server-with-multiple-parameters/
                    // And also sample code from https://github.com/ChrisGraham84/EtsyAPIConsumer
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Image img = Image.FromFile(localImageFilenames[i]);
                        string imageType = DetermineImageType(img);
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imageFormat = DetermineImageFormat(img);
                        byte[] imageByteArray;
                        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
                        IRestResponse response;


                        img.Save(ms, imageFormat);
                        imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();

                        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                        request.AddParameter("image", localImageFilenames[i]);
                        request.AddParameter("type", "image/" + imageType);
                        request.AddParameter("rank", imageRank++);
                        request.AddFile("image", imageByteArray, localImageFilenames[i], "image/" + imageType);


                        request.AddJsonBody(null);

                        request.Resource = "/listings/{0}/images".Replace("{0}", etsyListingId.ToString()); // eg "/listings/559242925/images";
                        request.Method = Method.POST;
                        response = restClient.Execute(request);
                    }                       
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                // Image n failed to up attached so skip it...
            }
        } // for...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine the image type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="localImage">The local image to be eventually uploaded to Etsy.</param>
    /// <returns>The image's type.  Default is Jpeg.</returns>
    private string DetermineImageType(Image localImage)
    {
        string imageType = "jpeg";


        if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imageType = "jpeg";
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imageType = "gif";
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imageType = "bmp";
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imageType = "png";
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imageType = "tiff";
        }

        return imageType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the image's image format.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="localImage">The local image to be eventually uploaded to Etsy</param>
    /// <returns>The image's format.  Default is Jpeg.</returns>
    private System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat DetermineImageFormat(Image localImage)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;


        if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif;
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp;
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
        }
        else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff.Equals(localImage.RawFormat))
        {
            imgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff;
        }

        return imgFormat;
    }
```

It's not a file size problem because I've tried with a 20K image file.

I think the problem is related to me not setting some boundary in the request??  None of the "solutions" I've seen make use of OAuthentication and RestSharp.

Brian Grinstead's article https://briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c/seemed promising but I don't understand how to integrate the Rest Client that's been set up with the Etsy keys to make the authenticated call.

[EDIT]

Pointers would be very much apprieciated.

Answer (score 1):

We set the `AlwaysMiltipartFormData` to true, and used `AddFileBytes` in the `RestRequest`. Also, we added the `Content-Type multipart/form-data` to the parameter list insetead of the header.
Maybe that works for you as well. Good luck.